# php telegram bot api show rows of database in inline keyboard

Tags: php, telegram

I am developing a telegram bot on the PHP language,
I would like in the inline keyboard to be able to display all the lines to find the transactions purchased by a customer,
When a customer buys a tool on my telegram channel he sees it in my purchases, then if he takes two orders at the same time the bot

will show the customer only the last products to buy I would like to recover them all.

It show only 1 row :
https://prnt.sc/E8r-LRwqYq0p

Here is datatable "transactions"
https://prnt.sc/g8vSxpAWl0BI

I tried this :

```
if ($update['callback_query']['data'] == 'mesachats')
        {

    $reqs = $base->prepare('SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE chatId = ?');
        $reqs->execute([$queryuserid]);
             $myscamas = $reqs->fetchAll();




    $message = "
<b> En cas de problème avec le bot veuillez contacter @CRUSIX.</b>

️ Vous pouvez retrouver ci-dessous la liste des scamas que vous avez acheter, cliquez dessus pour la télécharger / modifier le nom de domaine attribué ️

";


        foreach ($myscamas as $myscama)
        {
        $keyboards = json_encode([
    'inline_keyboard' => [

        [
            ['text' => '️ • '.$myscama['productName'], 'callback_data' => 'mesachats']
        ]



    ]
]);
    }
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: You are _overwriting_ `$keyboards` in each loop iteration there, I doubt that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Before the foreach

```
$keyboards = [];
```

in the foreach

$keyboards[] = json_encode([
'inline_keyboard' => [

```
    [
        ['text' => '️ • '.$myscama['productName'], 'callback_data' => 'mesachats']
    ];
```